# Data Frame Manipulation: Operation on Variables

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

I have a data frame called "Bycountry" like this:

Countries Norders
1   Algerie       1
2    France       2
3   Tunisie       3
4   Algerie       4
5 Allemagne       5
6    France       6

I want to do statistics on this dataframe:

- in country column, a summary of the countries (no duplicate)
- in numbers column, the sum by countries

I already installed `plyr` and `dplyr` packages so I know that I have to use `mutate()`, `summarise()`, `group_by()` but I don't know in which or and how.

```
   Otherbycountry <- data.frame(
          Countries = c("Algerie", "France", "Tunisie", "Algerie", 
          "Allemagne", "France"),
           Norders = c(1 , 2 , 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

The current result is a 1x1 tibble with the total sum of the numbers.

Comment: Hi @Jul, it will be easier to get help with this question if it is reproducible: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/3277821

Comment: Hi @sboysel I just edited my question, can you help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

## Code

```
library(dplyr)
Otherbycountry %>% 
    # grouping by country
    group_by(Countries) %>% 
    # sum of Norders column (for each group) 
    summarise(Norders_sum = sum(Norders)) %>% 
    # ungroup
    ungroup()
```

- Type `?group_by`, `?summarise` and `?group_by` inside R for more information about the functions.
- Read the section about [grouped summaries](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#grouped-summaries-with-summarise) (*R for Data Science by Garrett Grolemund and Hadley Wickham*) for more detail.

## Output

```
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
# Countries Norders_sum
# <fct>           <dbl>
# 1 Algerie             5
# 2 Allemagne           5
# 3 France              8
# 4 Tunisie             3
```